# Restrict .xml file and .cs file from download

Tags: c#, asp.net

In one of project i saw the below code.

```
        string FileName = Request.QueryString["filename"];
        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ";");
        response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/" + FileName));
        response.Flush();
        response.End();
```

which is used to download file from server. Now if someone changes filename (like web.config) in query string manually then it downloads config file also.

So please share your knowledge how to restrict from download based on file extension.

Comment: Never allow downloads from the root of your site. Always use a dedicated `Files`, `Content`, `Public` or `Uploads` area.

Comment: you are absolutely correct. But at this stage i can't change it because its used number of times across the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is usually done in IIS. But, if you wanna to it programmatically:

```
string[] forbiddenExtensions = new string[] {".config", ".abc", ".xml" };
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(FileName);
if (forbiddenExtensions.Contains(fi.Extension))
{
    //throw some error or something...
}
```

Comment: Is it possible by some configuration in config file or in IIS? I don't want to change code.

Comment: [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770504%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) can help you... **BUT**, you should definitively move your files to specific folder and/or refactor your code. Take some time and fix those holes...

Comment: .config extension is not there in list of MIME type.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll have to ask yourself whether you want to write code to let users download files present on the file system. The web server itself is perfectly fine handling file downloads and preventing access to files that shouldn't be shared.

If you're sure you want to do this, for example because you want some code to run before every download, then you should look at [creating a handler](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308001) instead. Then the web server will still first determine permissions and whatnot, in order to prevent malicious users from downloading sensitive files, and when allowed, your code will run before the download.

That being said, you don't want to serve files for download from your web root. Instead create a dedicated directory, say, "Downloads", and host your files for download from there. Then use `filename = Path.GetFileName(filename)` to prevent the user from navigating outside that directory (using `..` and/or `\`).